# Disable system.log completely 1.8

Tags: system.log

I have Magento 1.8 (yeah, I know!), but the system.log is huge every day.

In the admin I all ready disable the logging, but Magento does it anyway.

So now I chmod system.log to no write. This works for a few days.

But then Magento renames the file to system.log.bak and creates a new system.log that has write rights and gets huge in two days.

Does anyone know a way to completely disable the system.log for good?

Comment: Btw, module Mage_log is also disabled allready. But still logging.

Comment: refer this link :- https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/system-log.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I really hope Magento doesn't ignore this setting :-)

Comment: Your problem are done or not??